# how to have published npm package honor baseUrl from tsconfig.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, package

I am working on a npm library that is written in typescript.

in our project setup, we have a baseUrl in our tsconfig.json

```
"baseUrl": "src",
```

if we want to reference something under src

```
src
  |-folderA
       |-file1.ts
```

we can just do

```
import {...} from "folderA/file1"
```

e.g in our "src/index.ts" file we have below code

```
export * from "folderA/file1";
```

after we published our package and another project try to reference above package.

```
import { /*cannot import anything */} from "...package name..."
```

but if we change our package ("src/index.ts") to use relative path

```
import {...} from "./folderA/file1"
```

Other project will be able to perform import from our published npm package

any idea why published npm package doesn't honor baseUrl from tsconfig.json? (we do have tsconfig.json published in our package)

Comment: What is the entry point in your package's package.json?

Comment: Because `tsconfig.json` in your package is not used at all when users of your package are compiling their code - they are using their own `tsconfig.json`. Having relative paths in `index.ts` is the way to go. Also, the users of your package should not have to compile your typescript code at all - you should publish compiled `*.js` and`*.d.ts` files on `npm`, not `*.ts` files.

Comment: @artem I did only published *.d.ts file, however there was import statemtnt in *.d.ts file as well and they cannot resolve import

Comment: Then the last part of my comment does not apply, sorry. Generated toplevel `index.d.ts` file is indeed supposed to have mostly `import` statements, and if you look at how other packages are doing it, having relative imports there is the norm. Here are a couple examples:  https://unpkg.com/typescript-rest@1.2.0/dist/typescript-rest.d.ts    https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5.5.2/Rx.d.ts

Answer (score 0):

In tsconfig.json file

```json
"baseUrl":"src",
"paths":{
    "@components/*":["src/app/components/*"]
}
```

And you can import like below

```
import Test from `@components/test`
```